# Find parameters of a method with grep

Tags: grep

I need some help with a `grep` command (in the Bash).

In my source files, I want to list all unique parameters of a function. Background: I want to search through all files, to see, which permissions `([perm("abc")]` are used.

Example.txt:

```
if (x) perm("this"); else perm("that");
perm("what");
```

I'd like to have my `grep` output:

```
this
that
what
```

If I do my `grep` with this search expression

```
perm\(\"(.*?)\"\)
```

I'll get `perm("this)`, `perm("that")`, etc. but I'd like to have just the permissions: this and that and what.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a look-behind:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=perm\(")[^"]*' file
this
that
what
```

This looks for all the text occurring after `perm("` and until another `"` is found.

Note `-P` is used to allow this behaviour (it is a Perl regex) and `-o` to just print the matched item, instead of the whole line.

Comment: Thanks, +1. Unfortunately my bash version (3.2.51) doesn't support the -Po parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `gnu awk` version (due to multiple characters in `RS`)

```
awk -v RS='perm\\("' -F\" 'NR>1 {print $1}' file
this
that
what
```